# Column shows null in written "Select *" query, but is populated in "Select top 1000". How can I resolve this issue?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null, ssms

Long story short, I have a table loaded to my SQL Server. When I right-click "Select top 1000...", I can see the data is populated nicely.

However, when I write a query and run it, on the exact same table (no filters), columns show as NULL.

Has anyone seen this before? Is there a way to resolve the issue?

Comment: The results you see depend on the ordering of the rows -- and without an `order by` that can be any order.  You seem to have rows with lots of `NULL` values and you are seeing them when you run the query.

Comment: remove top 1000 from the query and execute.

Comment: Are You writing the query with the top 1000? Try write a query with any filter not NULL.

Comment: Are both of your methods using the same table in the same schema in the same database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gordon Linoff's answer made me check some of the columns I was using in the joins. One of my date columns was completely null and I was filtering on the date column in the view.